# How to take a string and put it in alphabetical order using C

Tags: c

Hi guys so I have this code that orders a sentence in alphabetical order:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}

int main(){
    char str[100];
    scanf("%[^'\n']s",str);
    char *word, *words[strlen(str)/2+1];
    int i, n;

    for(i=0;str[i];i++){
        str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
    }

    i=0;
    word = strtok(str, " ,.-:;?!");

    while(word != NULL){
        words[i++] = word;
        word = strtok(NULL, " ,.-:;?!");
    }

    n = i;
    qsort(words, n, sizeof(*words), cmp);

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        printf("%s ",words[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

this code receives a sentence from the user (imagine: "My/car/is/beautiful") and returns:

```
beautiful car is my
```

and i want it to give "My/beautiful/car/is" but i don't know how to do it.(privileging the capitalized words and printing the '/'.)

Comment: Instead of `scanf("%[^'\n']s",str);`, you almost certainly want `scanf("%99[^\n]",str);`

Comment: Remove the `tolower` and you will also have to write your own `strcmp` function to pass to `qsort`

Comment: You may be able to replace `strcmp()` with [`strcoll()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcoll.html), depending on your *locale* definitions.

Comment: sorry I rewritted my question, now it has what i want to know

Comment: Then you just need to remove the `tolower` and add printing slashes in your final printing loop.